# Create web hooks in vsts to use tfs aggregator Error Basic authentication requires a secure connection to the server.

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfs-aggregator

I tried to set web hooks in VSTS and install tfsaggregator in azure use [this manual](https://tfsaggregator.github.io/admin/install-webhooks/). But When I wanna to define a web hooks and try to test I have an error in connection:

[image]

[image]

Here is tfsaggregator web.config:

[image]

And HelloWorld.policies

[image]

I always have the Message:

**[Bug #5](http://fabrikam-fiber-inc.visualstudio.com/web/wi.aspx?pcguid=74e918bf-3376-436d-bd20-8e8c1287f465&id=5) (Some great new idea!) created by Jamal Hartnett.**

And the Error Message is:

**Basic authentication requires a secure connection to the server. (500)**

I followed exact steps in [manual](https://tfsaggregator.github.io/admin/install-webhooks/).

My url address is like:

https://tfsaggregator-webhooks-*****.azurewebsites.net/api/workitem

does any one have any idea? where is the problem?

Comment: Share your configuration file that contains your authentication section and the URL to your VSTS account. Redact the password or PAT.

Comment: @DanielMann Added

Comment: Does it work if you go to the URL `/api/workitem`?

Comment: @DanielMann Yes `/api/workitem` works perfectly

Comment: @Saeid How about using another browser, or launch the browser in private browsing?

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT I tried in 4 browsers and different team projects and private browsing and I get the same Error

Comment: @Saeid Any useful information in F12?

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT No special

Comment: @Saeid Any message in the TFS Aggregator log? Do you type the username listed in web.config?

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT No message, yes it's same username, If I change the username or password the Error message would be different

Comment: Did you deploy to Azure from the Github with "Master" branch directly?